# C# recall email from code behind on MS Exchange Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, exchange-server

I am on a server where running MS Exchange Server and I need to recall unread email after user open message in another application. In MS Outlook is possible to do a recall sent email but it is possible from code behind through MS Exchange API?

Comment: Yes - presuming you have the user's credentials. Please Google for some example script and play with what you find, then if you run into a specific problem edit your question to include your code and specific problem and we'll be here to help. We're about answering problems, not writing code, so showing you've tried will help you get meaningful answers.

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to code from you, but I don't find solution yet and I only asked if it is possible.

Comment: You're welcome, https://www.google.com/#q=c-sharp+access+user+sent+item+box+in+microsoft+exchange+server Good luck!

Comment: What's the point of recalling it then vs just going into the Recipients Mailbox and deleting the message ? Deleting a Message will be much easy to achieve then trying to use Recall.

Comment: I can not delete message in recipients mailbox because I need to do it from my email. In outlook I am log in to my email account and I sent email to "asd@mail.com" and I am able to recall this email without connect to "asd@mail.com" mailbox...